# How to connect to Sqlite database in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

i am having a problem with connectingto my .sqlite file database in Python. You can assume the file is in the same dir as the python file. And the name of the file is "data.sqlite". I have tried many different solutions on fixing it, without prevailing. IWhen i try to establish the connection, it claims it can not open the database because of the SQLAlchemy database URI being wrong, but in all cases where i have searched, or even used AI, they have all been not working. This is how i tried to solve it:

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite:///data.sqlite')
```

However, it gives me this error:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite:///data.sqlite')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

the desired outcome would be to be able to open the connection to the database, so i can actually do something with it.

Ways i have have tried to solve with was using just the database name and file extension as the URI like this:

```py
'data.sqlite'
```

however this made it so that Sqlite could not recognize the link. Then i tried using the absolute path without the sqlite syntax start.

```py
C:\\Users\\ADXXXXX\\OneDrive - XXB BXnk XXA\\Documents\\Dashtesting\\data.sqlite'
```

However, this resulted in the same problem as the last one. After this, i tried adding the Sqlite syntax start:

```py
sqlite:///C:\\Users\\ADXXXXX\\OneDrive - XXB BXnk XXA\\Documents\\Dashtesting\\data.sqlite'
```

However, this did also not work, and complained saying that it was unable to open the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the sqlite3 connection syntax requires the `sqlite://` prefix, this is something I have typically used with a SQLAlchemy connection.

As the file is located at the root, alongside the python script, using the following (sqlite3) should work as intended:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.sqlite')
```

In the event you are using SQLAlchemy the following should work:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///data.sqlite')
conn = engine.connect()
```